# Why properties defined are not used in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

At work, I often see some properties defined in pom.xml but not used while searching. So is it used to override the properties inherited from other pom.xml/dependencies?

Comment: What do you mean by `pom.xml but not used while searching.` ? Please give much more details...

Comment: It can also be code that was copied from another project pom. Standard stuffs. Can you give specific examples?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the properties are applied implicitly, e.g. when you specify

```xml
<properties>
  <java.version>19</java.version>
</properties>
```

Maven automatically propagates 19 into `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` of `maven-compiler-plugin` even if you don't specify mentioned properties explicitly within plugin configuration. Also IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA uses this property to set module's language level automatically.